# python/pandas: finding first occurences in dataframe by condition over a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe such as this:
`df = pd.DataFrame({"data": range(0, 100, 2)})`.

I have a list `targets = [1, 50, 70]`. I would like to find the indices of the first times the dataframe column is greater or equal to these values, which for this example is `[1, 25, 35]`.

For a single target I can filter by `df["data"].ge(target)` and then get the index with `idxmax`. Is there a nice, vectorized way to do this over an array, or do I need to iterate through my `targets` array one at a time?

Comment: Is the data in sorted order? If so, I would suggest [np.searchsorted()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html), because it is O(log N), which is faster than the O(N) of looking for the first true element.

Comment: The data should be sorted so I think that will work, thank you!